# Visual studio code python terminal not working on MacOS

Tags: python, macos, visual-studio-code

Hello Im a beginner in coding python ,  totally new on this, my terminal window shows the "zsh:command not found" error, it also shows the "python not found" error , appreciate any help I can get in this ,  Im running MacOs Monterey the latest version

I have tried installing extensions so far nothing

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Have you installed [Python](https://www.python.org/downloads/)? If you have installed, you have to check your environment variable.

Comment: what action are you using to run Python? Something from the Python extension? Something from the Code Runner extension?

Answer (score 1):

On mac as far as I remember there is only python3 alias, so to use python you type `python3`. You can also add other interpreter by adding line like

```
# Change path to your interpreter
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.1/bin:${PATH}" 
export PATH
```

to your .zshrc file(open for example with `nano ~/.zshrc`)

Answer (score -1):

Here are some things you can try.

1. Install latest version of python for your system from the official python repository https://www.python.org/downloads/
2. Restart Terminal/Vscode where you are attempting to run python